# Symfony2: Create a logout link

Tags: authentication, symfony, logout

I am managing users in my symfony2 project. I am able to login and logout without problems. Now, I would like to create a logout link (instead of typing app_dev.php/logout).

I have tryed

```
<a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

But this link is deleting the app_dev.php and i have only /logout which does not exist.

here is my security.yml

```
security:
  encoders:
    MDPI\BackendBundle\Entity\Users:
      id: mdpi.backend.backendencoder.class

  providers:
    secured_area:
     entity: { class: MDPI\BackendBundle\Entity\Users, property: email }

  firewalls:
    secured_area:
      pattern:    ^/
      anonymous: ~
      form_login:
        login_path:  /login
        check_path:  /login_check
      logout:
         path:   /logout
         target: /


  access_control:
    - { path: ^/(?!login)(.*), role: ROLE_admins }
    - { path: /login.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I created the link this way: (I use TWIG)

```
<a href="{{ path('user_logout') }}">Logout</a>
```

And in my "UserBundle", in the routing.yml file added

```
user_logout:
       pattern:   /logout
```

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes more. Will do it. Thx

Comment: Just a detail, In  Symfony3 the route needs to be configured slightly differently.

`user_logout:
       path:   /logout`

Answer (score 13):

When you are using the FOSUserBundle you can use

```
{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Symfony 2.7 you can use Twig [`logout_path`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#logout-path) or [`logout_url`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#logout-url) functions.